# Create new Producer from Kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

How to create new Kafka Producer from existing Consumer with java ?

Comment: What do you mean by new Kafka Producer? Do you just want to consume data and publish into another topic with some processing done?

Comment: no actually i just want to take the data from consumer and want to pass in new topic <<<<<<-------

Comment: pass in new topic with the help of new producer

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain what you *actually* want, based on the comments below

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a KafkaProducer from a KafkaConsumer instance.

You have to explicitly create a KafkaProducer using the same connection settings as your producer.

Considering the use case you mentioned (copying data from a topic to another), I'd recommend using Kafka Streams. There's actually an example in Kafka that does exactly that: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pipe/PipeDemo.java

Comment: Actual my task is to print the data from particular offset to particular off set  for example ->print the data from 151 offset to 351 offset .

Comment: for this i use consumer.seek and poll methods however it's not working properly

Comment: ConsumerRecords<String, AccountHolder> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1000));

        if (flag) {
            //consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("sudotest", 0), 29061);
            consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("sudotest",0), 2854);


            flag = false;
        }

        for (ConsumerRecord<String, AccountHolder> record : records)
            System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
    }
}

Comment: In the question you asked about Producer and now you're asking about consuming data at specific offsets. I'm not sure I understand how what you're doing

Comment: i use consumer .seek method to start printing the data from specific offset but -1 and 0 offset value printing by default that is why iam trying to use to use new producer and send the data in new topic after applying if loop condition that'is my agenda if iam wrong then please give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use the Kafka Streams library. It reads data from kafka topics and do some processing and write back to another topics.

That could be simpler approach for you. 
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/

Current limitation is, Source and destination cluster should be same with Kafka Streams.
Otherwise you need to use Processor API to define another destination cluster.

Another approach, is simply define a producer in the consumer program. Wherever your rule matches(based on offset or any conditions), call `producer.send()` method